# Enabling SSL on Apache2 causes address already in use error

Tags: https, security-certificate, apache2, httpd.conf, configuration

My server works just fine on a normal Apache2 install. Now, I'm trying to install subversion on this server using a guide I found on the net called: [Installation of Subversion on Ubuntu, with Apache, SSL, and BasicAuth](http://alephzarro.com/blog/2007/01/07/installation-of-subversion-on-ubuntu-with-apache-ssl-and-basicauth/).

However I get the following error:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
```

When I do `grep -rH 443 /etc/apache2/` I get results in two files: `ports.conf` and `sites-enabled/default-ssl`

I tried it both with and without that last `Listen 443` commented out, here's `ports.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

#Listen 443
```

And the first few lines of `default-ssl`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /this/isnt/relevant/probably.pem
        SSLProtocol all
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
```

And `netstat -an --inet | grep 443` returns nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself when I commend these lines out in `ports.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```